# side scrolling game with AndEngine and XML-Levels

Tags: xml, andengine, side-scroller

i just started a side-scrolling game with andengine using xml-levels and box2d.

does anyone know how get the level scrolling when i move the player, so that the player stays in the center of the screen?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `Camera.setChaseEntity` (With your player object).

Comment: i tried this already. does not seem to work.
first problem is, that i have a black gap on the left side and second the camera does not move.

Comment: `setChaseEntity` is the way to do it. If it doesn't work, it has to be a problem in your code. Please post it

Comment: ist okay. thx. I got it working with myCamera.setCenter(mySprite.getX(),mySprite.getY());

Comment: That's exactly what `setChaseEntity` does. Every loop of the update thread it repositions the camera center to be the entity's coordinates.